# Firestore setting collection based on users value

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

I'm not sure how to properly integrate this. I'm using bare react native with firebase 8.2.3. I'm trying to add a memo function into my app where users can check there memos on there home screen when first opening up the app. I have a separate collection called 'users' In that collection are stored values for each user with an "Agency" value. I want to separate memos based on agency. For example there are multiple collections called "HR,Finance,Managment....etccc" I set up a function to pull the user data first to determine which agency they are from and then another function to fetch there memos. When I run this in the simulator it does not set the agency in the collection.. it just hangs.. here is what I wrote.

```
const HomeScreen = ({navigation}) => {
  const {user} = useContext(AuthContext);
  const [posts, setPosts] = useState(null);
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);
  const [deleted, setDeleted] = useState(false);
  const [userData, setUserData] = useState(null);
  
  
  const getUser = async() => {
    await firestore()
    .collection('users')
    .doc(user.email)
    .get()
    .then((documentSnapshot) => {
      if( documentSnapshot.exists ) {
        console.log('User Data', documentSnapshot.data());
        setUserData(documentSnapshot.data());
      }
    })
  }
 
 
  useEffect(() => {
    getUser();
  }, []);

 
 

  const fetchPosts = async () => {
    try {
      const list = [];

      

      await firestore()
        .collection(userData.agency)
        .orderBy('postTime', 'desc')
        .get()
        .then((querySnapshot) => {
          // console.log('Total Posts: ', querySnapshot.size);

          querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
            const {
              userId,
              post,
              postImg,
              postTime,
              likes,
              comments,
            } = doc.data();
            list.push({
              id: doc.id,
              userId,
              userName: 'Test Name',
              userImg:
                'omitted',
              postTime: postTime,
              post,
              postImg,
              liked: false,
              likes,
              comments,
            });
          });
        });

      setPosts(list);

      if (loading) {
        setLoading(false);
      }

      console.log('Posts: ', posts);
    } catch (e) {
      console.log(e);
    }
  };



  useEffect(() => {
    fetchPosts();
  }, []);
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated :)
I'm still very new at this :)

Comment: Can you share a template of your data structure in the database (Firestore)

Comment: Please edit your question and add the information Medic305 asked for, and please also respond using @.

Comment: @FistonEmmanuel its nothing crazy.. I have one collection called "users" that is wear the agency value is stored for each user. Then I have separate collections for each agency.

Comment: @Medic305  you mention  you have multiple collections called "HR,Finance,Managment,... this should be replaced by one collection called departments.

Most of challenges you are experiencing should be caused by your database architecture.

Comment: It's going o be hard to provide effective solution without know about collections you have and relationship between them

Comment: I think its not so much a firebase firestore issue it seems that my fetchpost is completing before getuser is complete. So the collection is never set for the fetchpost